# Stopping Python container is slow - SIGTERM not passed to python process?

Tags: python, docker, terminate

I made a simple python webserver based on [this example](https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/), which runs inside Docker

```
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

COPY src src
CMD ["python", "/app/src/api.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo starting entrypoint
set -x
exec "$@"
```

Stopping the container took very long, altough the `exec` statement with the JSON array syntax should pass it to the python process. I assumed a problem with `SIGTERM` no being passed to the container. I added the following to my `api.py`script to detect `SIGTERM`

```
def terminate(signal,frame):
  print("TERMINATING")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, terminate)

    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))
    webServer.serve_forever()
```

Executed without Docker `python3 api/src/api.py`, I tried

```
kill -15 $(ps -guaxf | grep python | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

to send `SIGTERM` ([15 is the number code of it](https://www.stackabuse.com/handling-unix-signals-in-python/)). The script prints *TERMINATING*, so my event handler works. Now I run the Docker container using docker-compose and press CTRL + C. Docker says *gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)* but doesn't print my terminating message from the event handler.

I also tried to run docker-compose in detached mode, then run `docker-compose kill -s SIGTERM api` and view the logs. Still no message from the event handler.

Comment: Try something like `import os` then `print('My process id is: {}'.format(os.getpid()))`. Docker only waits for process id 1 to cleanly shutdown (not sure about compose, haven't used it extensively). If your log doesn't contain "My process id is: 1", its likely that the process isn't being given time to respond to a sigterm and is not cleanly shutting down.

Comment: Also be aware of the different behavior of a
`ENTRYPOINT python main.py` and a `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]`. The first runs Python with PID 1 (so receiving all signals), the latter runs a shell with PID 1, so **your Python script will never see any signals**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the script runs as pid 1 as desired and setting `init: true` in `docker-compose.yml` doesn't seem to change anything, I took a deeper drive in this topic. This leads me figuring out multiple mistakes I did:

### Logging

The approach of printing a message when `SIGTERM` is catched was designed as simple test case to see if this basically works before I care about stopping the server. But I noticed that no message appears for two reasons:

#### Output buffering

When running a long term process in python like the HTTP server (or any `while True` loop for example), there is **no output** displayed when starting the container attached with `docker-compose up` (no `-d` flag). To receive live logs, we need to start python with the `-u` flag or set the env variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE`.

#### No log piping after stop

But the main problem was not the output buffering (this is just a notice since I wonder why there was no log output from the container). When canceling the container, [`docker-compose` stops piping logs to the console.](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7135) This means that from a logical perspective it can't display anything that happens *AFTER* CTRL + C is pressed.

To fetch those logs, we need to wait until `docker-compose` has stopped the container and run `docker-compose logs`. It will print all, including those generated after CTRL + C is pressed. Using `docker-compose logs` I found out that `SIGTERM` is passed to the container and my event handler works.

### Stopping the webserver

With those knowledge I tried to stop the webserver instance. First this doesn't work because it's not enough to just call `webServer.server_close()`. Its required to exit explicitely after any cleanup work is done like this:

```
def terminate(signal,frame):
  print("Start Terminating: %s" % datetime.now())
  webServer.server_close()
  sys.exit(0)
```

When `sys.exit()` is not called, the process keeps running which results in ~10s waiting time before Docker kills it.

### Full working example

Here a demo script that implement everything I've learned:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import signal
from datetime import datetime
import sys, os

hostName = "0.0.0.0"
serverPort = 80

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(bytes("Hello from Python Webserver", "utf-8"))

webServer = None

def terminate(signal,frame):
  print("Start Terminating: %s" % datetime.now())
  webServer.server_close()
  sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, terminate)

    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s with pid %i" % ("0.0.0.0", 80, os.getpid()))
    webServer.serve_forever()
```

Running in a container, it could be stopped very fast without waiting for Docker to kill the process:

```
$ docker-compose up --build -d
$ time docker-compose down
Stopping python-test_app_1 ... done
Removing python-test_app_1 ... done
Removing network python-test_default

real    0m1,063s
user    0m0,424s
sys     0m0,077s
```

Comment: You haven't gotten much love for this answer, but thank you. This kind of thing needs to be documented somewhere. It's going to save me a lot of time in the long-run.

Comment: Also, you should accept your own answer so that it is easier to find.

Answer (score 14):

Docker runs your application, per default, in foreground, so, as PID 1, this said, the process with the PID 1 as a special meaning and specific protections in Linux.

This is highlighted in `docker run` documentation:

> **Note**
>
> A process running as PID 1 inside a container is treated specially by Linux: it ignores any signal with the default action. As a result, the process will not terminate on `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` unless it is coded to do so.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground*</sup>

In order to fix this, you can run the container, in a single container mode, with the flag `--init` of `docker run`:

> You can use the `--init` flag to indicate that an init process should be used as the PID 1 in the container. Specifying an init process ensures the usual responsibilities of an init system, such as reaping zombie processes, are performed inside the created container.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process*</sup>

The same configuration is possible in `docker-compose`, simply by specifying `init: true` on the container.

An example would be:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: alpine:latest
    init: true
```

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#init*</sup>