# How to run a Flask app in debug mode with using pipenv and docker?

Tags: docker, flask, debugging, pipenv

I set my `app.py` to debug mode:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', title='Title Here')

# ...
# more routes here
# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The Python library called `geopandas` is messing my local machine up, that's why I decided to dockerise my app, and it works perfectly! (Except the flask debug mode)

My `Dockerfile` looks like this. I tried the `debugpy` library with no success:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as base

# Setup env
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1


FROM base AS python-deps

# Install pipenv and compilation dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc

# Install python dependencies in /.venv
COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install geopandas
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install debugpy
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install --deploy
CMD pipenv debugpy

FROM base AS runtime

# Copy virtual env from python-deps stage
COPY --from=python-deps /.venv /.venv
ENV PATH="/.venv/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /home


# Install application into container
COPY . .
```

Then I build the image with this:

`docker build -t <IMAGE-NAME:HERE> .`

Then I initialise the docker container with this script:

`docker run --rm -ti --mount type=bind,source=/"$(pwd)",target=/home -p 5000:5000 <IMAGE-NAME:HERE> flask run --port 5000 --host 0.0.0.0 --debugger`

And everything is working but the debug mode:

```
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Docker is designed to isolate the container environment from your host system; it's not necessarily a good match for a day-to-day development or debugging environment.  Your Dockerfile doesn't seem to be installing any OS-level packages beyond a C compiler.  Can you use `pipenv` on your host system without Docker?  (How is `geopandas` causing problems?)

Comment: Yes, I can use `pipenv` on my machine without Docker. `Pipfile` contains all necessary packages to be installed for my app and as I said, everything is working well in the docker container apart from debug mode. The `geopandas` problem is very complicated, I tried to solve it in multiple ways, and somebody recommended to try with docker and finally it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to answer your question:

```
flask --debug run --port 5000 --host 0.0.0.0
```

[Debug](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/cli/#debug-mode) mode enables `--debugger` and also `--reload`.

I have had great success using Docker as the runtime for my Flask application during development. It makes development quite a bit easier, especially when paired with Docker compose once your app grows a bit and you need other services like a database or a redis instance.

I'm a little confused as to why your `CMD` is before your runtime stage, and why you're using `pipenv debugpy` instead of `pipenv run debugpy`. (That said, I have no experience with debugpy, so maybe this is actually correct.) Anyway, I'd encourage you to [investigate `ENTRYPOINT`](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/understanding-dockers-cmd-and-entrypoint-instructions) to see if it might simplify invocation.

As an aside, you should consider creating a `docker-compose.yml` file and starting your service with `docker compose up`. The docker CLI incantation above is already starting to become unwieldy. This is untested, but should get you started:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: <IMAGE_NAME>
   
    # Fix slow shutdown of web container
    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62854251/1749551
    init: true
    
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development # Implies --debug
      PORT: 5000
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    restart: always
    entrypoint: "flask run --host=0.0.0.0"

    # To enable pdb within Docker:
    # https://hackernoon.com/debugging-using-pdb-in-dockerized-environment-i21n2863
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

    # Bind the project directory into the container so changes are reflected by Flask
    volumes:
      - .:/home
```

And lastly, be conscious of what `COPY . .` [will pick up and add to your image](https://snyk.io/blog/10-docker-image-security-best-practices/).

Comment: The location of `CMD` within the file is due to being noob with Docker. Thank you, your answer and links helped me a lot!