# Understanding Docker + FastAPI startup and Shutdown

Tags: docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I have been struggling to figure out why my uvicorn + fastapi app doesnt get a sigterm and docker compose needs 10 seconds before it sends a sigkill to terminate.  I wanted to leave out the heavy lifting in my app and wanted to build a very simple sample app that will demonstrate  the problem.  I ran into a new problem while doing so.  I need some help here to understand what is going on.

My sample program is attached

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as the parent image
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app


# Copy the requirements.txt files to install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# FastAPI app
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
CMD ["uvicorn", "fastsample:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8888"]
```

When this program starts and I press Ctrl+C, I see the following on the console

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 uvidemo
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8888 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     172.17.0.1:41148 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     172.17.0.1:41148 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     172.17.0.1:41148 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     172.17.0.1:41148 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     172.17.0.1:41148 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
^CINFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Finished server process [1]
ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 686, in lifespan
    await receive()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/lifespan/on.py", line 137, in receive
    return await self.receive_queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/queues.py", line 158, in get
    await getter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

Why do I get this exception?  Is there a bug in my code / uvicorn / fastapi that I am missing here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `--lifespan <str> - Set the Lifespan protocol implementation. Options: 'auto', 'on', 'off'. Default: 'auto'.` according to the [docs](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/). Could you try specifying lifespan as `off`.

Comment: As for your initial question; check [this](https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/) article and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853875/stopping-python-container-is-slow-sigterm-not-passed-to-python-process) answer.

Comment: thanks for the links @doneforaiur I found out that there is a bug in uvicorn related to SIGINT handling and I suspect this could be the reason.